# How can one stay out of Israel?

Tags: halacha, travel, korban

According to Halacha[1], when one travels overseas, one has to bring a Toda.

Imagine a Jew who lives in Morocco (with a hetter, such that he happened to find a Rov there he couldn't get in Israel).

1. He goes overseas. Now he has to bring a Toda.
2. He goes to Yerushalaim, brings two Todas (one for the original obligation and one for the new journey across the Mediterranean). He turns around and goes home.
3. How he's home in Morocco, and owes another Toda for his trip there. Now he has a chiyuv to go back and bring another Toda for his trip back to Morocco.
4. Goto 2.

He seems stuck in an infinite loop. What should he do to avoid it (even overland journeys will obligate him in a Toda as there are deserts in the way).

[1]: אם על תודה יקריבנו: אם על דבר הודאה על נס שנעשה לו, כגון יורדי הים והולכי מדברות וחבושי בית האסורים וחולה שנתרפא שהם צריכין להודות שכתוב בהן (תהלים קז כא - כב) יודו לה' חסדו ונפלאותיו לבני אדם ויזבחו זבחי תודה. אם על אחת מאלה נדר שלמים הללו, שלמי תודה הן, וטעונות לחם האמור בענין, ואינן נאכלין אלא ליום ולילה, כמו שמפורש כאן: http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?tDate=3%2F24%2F2015&view=ds

Comment: 1) You might want to make explicit you mean in Temple times. 2) Don't you have to come back 3 times a year anyway?

Comment: @Yishai דא"ר אמי כל אדם שיש לו קרקע עולה לרגל ושאין לו קרקע אין עולה לרגל and ורבי יהודה בן בתירא שלא עלה לרגל י"ל שלא היה לו קרקע או זקן היה שאינו יכול להלך ברגליו דפטור מפסח כמו מראיה א"נ נציבין חו"ל היא כדמוכח בסיפרי בפ' ראה ועוד בתרגום ירושלמי (בראשית י) וארך ואכד וכלנה בארץ שנער מתרגם והדס ונציבין וקטיספי:

Comment: Re: Baal Te'acher, so come a week early. If you are talking about someone who is potur from Aliya LeRegel (which is not at all obvious that this excludes everyone who lives outside E.Y., but there are such opinions) then they are potur from Baal Te'acher as well ([Rosh Hashana 6b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=6b&format=pdf) near the bottom).

Comment: @Yishai, sounds like an answer.

Comment: @msh210, I would like a more definitive source that says this is the conclusion before making an answer, but in any event, I think the question would be better if it made explicit it was talking about B'zman HaBayis and someone who is otherwise Potur from Aliya LeRegel (because they live outside E.Y. or otherwise).